# How to Filter Items From A Table with Search

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

```
<input type="text" id="inputhair" onkeyup="hair()" placeholder="hair color...">





<table id="customers" class="customers">
  <tr class="parent" data-toggle="toggle">
    <th id="rank" style="text-align:center">#</th>
    <th id="name" style="text-align:center">Name</th>
    <th id="name" style="text-align:center"></th>

  </tr>

  <tbody class="content" >

<div class="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="name">Object A</td>
    <td class="down"><button        onclick="toggleText()"         type="button" class="collapsible" id="1">+</button></td>
  </tr>
  </div>

  <tr class="panel" id="1a"  colspan="3">
<div class="panel" >

      <td class="expand" >

<div class="hair">Black</div>



      </td>
      </div>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
  </table>
```

I'm trying to filter out two rows (name and details) of an object from this table if it doesn't match what is searched, but it is not doing anything on the actual website. Please respond if you can. Thank you

Number
        Name
        
    
      
    
    
    
    
      
        1
        Object A
        +
      
      
    
    
    
    
    
        
    Black

I tried doing (I have more objects like object 1 all with two lines)...

```
function hair() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("inputhair");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("customers");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  // for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
  //   td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
  //   var hairColor = document.getElementsByClassName("hair")[i/2].innerHTML;
  //   if (hairColor) {
  //     if (hairColor.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
  //       tr[i].style.display = "";
  //     } else {


  //       tr[i].style.display = "none";
  //       tr[i-1].style.display = "none";


  //     }
  //   }
  // }



  for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    var hairColor = document.getElementsByClassName("hair")[i/2].innerHTML;
    if (hairColor) {
      if ((hairColor.toUpperCase).includes(filter)) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {


        tr[i].style.display = "none";
        tr[i-1].style.display = "none";


      }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: FYI, the html is a mess... you have `div` inside `table`, `tbody` after `tr`. Javascript produces error. Try fix these first

Comment: just use [datatable](https://datatables.net) to avoid headache, it is very easy to implement.

Comment: also, you are searching for `.hair` class in entire DOM, instead of within the table column/row, this makes the loop useless.

Comment: Is this a class assignment? I've seen other questions with simular patterns lately.